# Conditional formating of a TextBlock within a Listbox’s DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

It’s my first wcf & I’m running into some trouble with what seems to be a basic XAML concept.

Somehow the DataTrigger / Binding in the “PriorityStyle” is not working. I guess this is because of a context issue but looking around I haven’t manage to find the answers.

```
<UserControl … >

<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="PriorityStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="High">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="3">
            ...
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="Priority" Text="{Binding Priority}" Foreground ="#014f7c" Style="{StaticResource PriorityStyle}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>

            <!-- DataBinding work in this Context, But in Style I cannot use a TargetName -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="High">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" />
```

Comment: I don't see where your `ListBox` is getting its data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @HighCore mentioned not sure where your setting the Source for your `ListBox`, but provided your binding works in the Style for `ListBoxItem` you can try a **work-around**

```
<Style x:Key="PriorityStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Priority, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="High">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but your also binding `Priority` property to `Text` in the `TextBlock` with `PriorityStyle` anyways. So you could also just do:

```
<Style x:Key="PriorityStyle"
       TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="Black" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Text"
             Value="High">
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

this way you don't even need a binding traversing through your element tree

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why this would be preferable to setting ItemsSource on the ListBox? I would have thought doing something like <ListBox ... ItemsSource={Binding} /> would be easier(slightly shorter), clearer(first place to look would be itemssource and not in a style!) and more conceptually correct(i can imagine changing collection bound to listbox in future updates instead of having to manually change each bound property in the style).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, as I stated in the beginning of the answer with the given info I wasn't sure where the source for listbox was set. Setting item source in listbox xaml should be what's preferred. Stating that, I'm not setting any item source in the Style either. Was just merely building on OP's comment of his DataTrigger in Style of ListBoxItem working fine and hence suggested a work around to use its DataContext

Comment: The Binding is actually done at runtime using 
RequestListBox.ListBox.ItemsSource = response.getListValues;

Answer (score 1):

I found out the real issue to my problem. It was not in fact a binding issues but a Style issue.

I didn’t include it in the original XAML as I did some wrongful cleaning in order to make it clearer. I was including in my Textblock a “Foreground” attribute an this last one was indeed overriding my style attribute. Removing it and including the “Default Foreground” Value in the Style Setter was the answer. Beginners mistake.

So, kudos to Viv, for pointing out the right direction & for the nice “RelativeSource” example. And sorry again for my bad question, a lesson learned here.

```
    <Style x:Key="PriorityStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6c6d6f" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Critical">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <TextBlock Name="Summary" Text="{Binding _Summary}" Style="{StaticResource PriorityStyle}" />
```