# Conditional formatting of a XAML listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am incredibly new to working with UWP. I apologize if this is something basic.

I'm going through some of the samples provided by Microsoft on GitHub. ( https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView )

What I'm attempting to do, is to use the XAML ListView example, but apply some conditional formatting to the list if a condition is met. Such as if Contact.Position == "Developer", change the color of the text to green.

The solution I found in the link below looked promising, however, the style triggers using in WPF are not available in UWP .
[Conditional formating of a TextBlock within a Listbox’s DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623615/conditional-formating-of-a-textblock-within-a-listbox-s-datatemplate)

The XAML generated for each item in the listView is defined as:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="SpectraListViewTemplate" x:DataType="data:spectraClass">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                 Width ="32"
                 Height="32"
                 Margin="6"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Fill="LightGray"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=Ellipse, Path=Width}"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=Ellipse, Path=Height}"
                   Margin="6"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{x:Bind Id}"
                   x:Phase="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="SpectraListViewTemplateNameTextBox"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{x:Bind Name}" 
                   x:Phase="1"  
                   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                   Margin="12,6,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Text="{x:Bind Date}" 
                    x:Phase="2"
                    Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                    Margin="12,0,0,6"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Does anyone have some advice or a direction I should be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209903) to achieve this.

Code:

```
//Add the below code in your references in xaml
xmlns:converters="using:MyProject.Converter"

//Add this part to the resources in the page
<Page.Resources>
        <converters:PersonToColorConverter x:Key="PersonToColorConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

//This could be a part of your ListView DataTemplate.
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="{Binding Position,Converter{StaticResource PersonToColorConverter}}" />
```

Now create a converter class called PersonToColorConverter and use the below code.

```
public class PersonToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
          SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
          string personPosition = value.ToString();
          if(personPosition!=null && personPosition.Equals("Developer"))
          {
                brush.Color = Colors.Green;
          }
          else
          {
                brush.Color = Colors.White;
          }
          return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting some errors when trying to compile this. The compiler is say that PersonToColorConverter does not exist in the namespace.

To the stock example I linked, I added:

On MasterDetailSelection.xaml
<cod><Page 
...
    xmlns:converters="using:ListViewSample" ></code>

Then I created a new class in the root of the project named converterClass.cs and pasted in your c# inside the namespace ListViewSample.

Comment: I fixed it. Oddly enough it seemed to compile fine after I restarted. 

It worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!